How to start existing cluster in Apache Solr?
I'm running Apache Solr in localmachine. I maintain a set of data and collections in a cluster. Every day, I have to use new cloud creating solr command.
solr start -e cloud

After assigning the ports to the cloud, I have to give the collection name. If I gave the existing collection name, then Solr only asks me to reuse or create_new_collection.

Collection 'cluster_books' already exists!
Do you want to re-use the existing collection or create a new one? Enter 1 to reuse, 2 to create new [1]:

How to start an existing cluster in preferred port number initially? Without in the way of starting a new cloud. 
Starting existing collection in cluster in preferred port, not in the way of creating new one.

Show how you are setting the ports and name, so we can help work out what the issue is.

Just solr start? -e is to load example data.

Now I'm using solr start -e cloud after assigning the ports, it asks for collection name there I give existing collection name. Then only it asks me to reuse the existing collection in solr server on assigned port. Without this process, how can I start the existing collection in solr server directly on preferred ports. Is there any cmd available for direct start.
